# Doxygen page generation from parts of other pages

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I have one file (say file1.doxy) with doxygen comments:

```
/**
 * Comment block 1
*/

...

/**
 * Comment block 2
 */

...

/**
 * Comment block 3
 */
```

And I want to create the file file2.doxy of which output is the same as:

```
/**
 * Comment block 1
 *
 * Comment block 3
 */
```

Actually I want to refer to file file1.doxy from file file2.doxy and not to copy-paste information from file1.doxy, but I can insert needed marking tags into file1.doxy.

Is it possibly to do so with doxygen?

Answer (score 3):

you could use [`\verbinclude <file-name>`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdverbinclude), like this:

`file1.doxy`:

```
/**
 * @verbinclude file1.doc
 */
function f1() {}

/**
 * @verbinclude file2.doc
 */
function f2() {}

/**
 * @verbinclude file3.doc
 */
function f3() {}
```

`file2.doxy`:

```
/**
 * @verbinclude file1.doc
 *
 * @verbinclude file3.doc
 */
function f1() {}
```

with `file1.doc`, `file2.doc`, `file3.doc` containing `Comment block 1`, `Comment block 2`, and `Comment block 3`, respectively. for this to work, you have to set the [`EXAMPLE_PATH`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_example_path) in your `Doxyfile` to the path of `file{1,2,3}.doc` (*). this won't expand @ doxygen commands in `file{1,2,3}.doc`, though.

an alternative could be using doxygen [preprocessing](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html) or [`INPUT_FILTER`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input_filter).

(*) you might also have to set [`EXTRACT_ALL`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extract_all) to `YES`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the nature of the original comment blocks, yes you can use the [@copydoc](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopydoc) command in your Doxygen comments to pull copies of blocks into another file.